# ElasticSearch C# client (NEST): access nested aggregation results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, aggregation

I have the following query in NEST (ElasticSearch C# client), note the nested aggregation:

```
            var query = _elasticClient.Search<Auth5209>(s => s
                .Size(0)
                .Aggregations(a=> a
                    .Terms("incidentID", t=> t
                        .Field(f=>f.IncidentID)
                        .Size(5)
                        .Aggregations(a2 => a2
                            .Stats("authDateStats", s1=>s1.Field(f=>f.AuthEventDate))
                        )
                    )                        
                )
                );
```

This correctly generates the following query:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "incidentID": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "incidentID",
        "size": 5
      },
      "aggs": {
        "authDateStats": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "authEventDate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which gives me the following results:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "incidentID" : {
        "buckets" : [{
                "key" : "0A631EB1-01EF-DC28-9503-FC28FE695C6D",
                "doc_count" : 233,
                "authDateStats" : {
                    "count" : 233,
                    "min" : 1401167036075,
                    "max" : 1401168969907,
                    "avg" : 1401167885682.6782,
                    "sum" : 326472117364064
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I access the "authDateStats" section.  When I debug I don't see any way to access the data.

[image]

Comment: Here is the example for nested aggregations using Nest.
https://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/aggregations/nested.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you already figured this out but you can access the nested aggregations, it's just in a base class, you can see it in Nest.KeyItem.base.base.Aggregations in the debugger.

Answer (score 6):

Neither the official documentation nor the answers here fully work for nest 2.0+.  Although the answer from jhilden did get started me down the right path.

Here is a working example of a similar query which can be used with nest 2.0+:

```
        const string termsAggregation = "device_number";
        const string topHitsAggregation = "top_hits";

        var response = await _elasticsearchClient.Client.SearchAsync<CustomerDeviceModel>(s => s
            .Aggregations(a => a
                .Terms(termsAggregation, ta => ta
                    .Field(o => o.DeviceNumber)
                    .Size(int.MaxValue)
                    .Aggregations(sa => sa
                        .TopHits(topHitsAggregation, th => th
                            .Size(1)
                            .Sort(x => x.Field(f => f.Modified).Descending())
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        if (!response.IsValid)
        {
            throw new ElasticsearchException(response.DebugInformation);
        }

        var results = new List<CustomerDeviceModel>();
        var terms = response.Aggs.Terms(termsAggregation);

        foreach (var bucket in terms.Buckets)
        {
            var hit = bucket.TopHits(topHitsAggregation);
            var device = hit.Documents<CustomerDeviceModel>().First();
            results.Add(device);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working sample of accessing an inner aggregation:

```
        const string aggName = "LocationIDAgg";
        const string aggNameTopHits = "LatestForLoc";
        var response = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<PlacementVerificationES>(s => s
            .Query(BuildQuery(filter, null))                
            .Size(int.MaxValue)
            .Aggregations(a=> a
                .Terms(aggName, t=> t
                    .Field(f=>f.LocationID)
                    .Size(100)
                    .Aggregations(innerAgg => innerAgg
                        .TopHits(aggNameTopHits, th=> th
                            .Size(1)
                            .Sort(x=>x.OnField(f=> f.Date).Descending())
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ).VerifySuccessfulResponse();

        //var debug = response.GetRequestString();
        var agBucket = (Bucket)response.Aggregations[aggName];

        var output = new List<PlacementVerificationForReporting>();
        // ReSharper disable once LoopCanBeConvertedToQuery
        // ReSharper disable once PossibleInvalidCastExceptionInForeachLoop
        foreach (KeyItem i in agBucket.Items)
        {
            var topHits = (TopHitsMetric)i.Aggregations[aggNameTopHits];
            var top1 = topHits.Hits<PlacementVerificationES>().Single();
            var reportingObject = RepoToReporting(top1);
            output.Add(reportingObject);
        }

        return output;
```